# Paste style to virtual layer from another layer

Tags: qgis, style, virtual-layer

My virtual layer disappears when I paste a style from another layer. I've done this process before and it worked fine, so I'm not sure what the problem is now. Here are my steps:

1. create virtual layer with one field
2. copy style from layer

[image]

3. paste it to the virtual layer. You can see the symbology style is there. But, the map is blank?

[image]

I haven't changed anything else on the virtual layer after creating it. The only thing different this time was that a message popped up stating the virtual layer already exists (because I copied the style a  few times while troubleshooting), then asks if I want to overwrite it. I click yes. I'm not sure why I can't see the virtual layer (and yes, I 'zoomed to layer' and checked the CRS).

EDIT: Here is that warning message. Not sure if it has anything to do with what I'm experiencing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer just presented itself to me. As I stated before, when I created the virtual layer I queried the layer so that I only see one field in the virtual layer:
`Select geometry, "Landcover" from "Landcover Early 1800s"`
This "Landcover" field was originally created in the field calculator based off another field called "MAP".

I noticed that in the Layer Styling of this virtual layer that I'm having problems with the value is set to MAP. Funny, that field isn't in my virtual layer? So, i clicked the Value drop-down and chose "Landcover".

[image]

[image]